# Looking for the name of a special map function

Tags: haskell

I'm new to Haskell and looking for the name of a function (or generally, the name of the concept) that acts as such:

The function takes two arguments:
1. A list of elements [T]
2. A function that takes a T, and returns a Maybe U.

The function's output is as follows:
If all elements in the list map to Some U, then return Some [U].
Otherwise, return None.

i.e. if any of the mapped values are null, then return null, otherwise just return the mapped values.

Comment: In the future, you can find functions easier by using [Hoogle](https://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=%28a+-%3E+Maybe+b%29+-%3E+%5Ba%5D+-%3E+Maybe+%5Bb%5D). Searching the type signature of your desired function found `mapM`, `forM`, and `traverse` immediately.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Haskell report calls it `sequence . map f`, also called `mapM f`. Nowadays you can call it `traverse f` (GHC 7.10+).

## Map and sequence

Let us think about the type of your function:

```
withList :: (a -> Maybe b) -> [a] -> Maybe [b]
```

The canonical function for mapping a list to another one is `map`, so we can use that as starting point:

```
withListNotYet :: (a -> Maybe b) -> [a] -> [Maybe b]
withListNotYet f xs = map f xs
```

Now we have a list of `Maybe b`, but we want to get the `Maybe` outside. This is essentially what `sequence` does:

```
sequence :: Monad m => [m a] -> m [a]
sequence []     = return []
sequence (x:xs) = do
  y  <- x
  ys <- sequence xs
  return (y : ys)
```

Since `Maybe` is an instance of `Monad`, we can use `sequence` after `withListNotYet` and end up with our implementation for `withList`:

```
withList f xs = sequence (map f xs)
```

Since this is a common operation, it has has a name: `mapM`:

```
withList f xs = mapM f xs
-- or
withList = mapM
```

## Traversable

During the ["burning bridges proposal"](https://wiki.haskell.org/Foldable_Traversable_In_Prelude), `mapM`'s type changed from

```
mapM     :: Monad m                        => (a -> m b) -> [a] -> m [b]
```

to

```
mapM     :: (Monad m, Traversable t)       => (a -> m b) -> t a -> m (t b)
```

There was already a similar function at that time, called `traverse`:

```
traverse :: (Applicative f, Traversable t) => (a -> f b) -> t a -> f (t b)
```

As you can see, the type signature is very similar. The same GHC version that changed `mapM`'s type also made `Applicative` a base class of `Monad`, see [Functor-Applicative-Monad-Proposal](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/wiki/Migration/7.10#base-4.8.0.0). So nowadays you can usually use `traverse` or `mapM`. The former is the younger, more general variant, while the latter is the older, historical variant.

And if you have a look at the `Traversable` class, you will notice that `mapM = traverse` by default.

Comment: This answer was most relevant to my needs.

Comment: Just a small remark: historically, `mapM` existed first. `traverse` came later. And `Applicative m => Monad m` came also later. Since the Applicative/Monad proposal and the Foldable/Traversable proposal you can exchange `mapM` and `traverse`. Nowadays, unless one specified another variant, `mapM = traverse`.

Answer (score 12):

This is `traverse` defined in the [`Traversable`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/Data-Traversable.html) class:

```
traverse :: Traversable t, Applicative f => (a -> f b) -> t a -> f (t b)
```

in your example `t` is list and `f` is `Maybe` e.g.

```
traverse (\x -> if x < 5 then Just x else Nothing) [1,2,3]
> Just [1,2,3]

traverse (\x -> if x < 5 then Just x else Nothing) [1,2,3, 9]
> Nothing
```

Answer (score 5):

The function is called [`traverse`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/Data-Traversable.html#v:traverse), from [`Data.Traversable`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/Data-Traversable.html).

The type might surprise at first because it is quite abstract:

`traverse :: (Applicative f,Traversable t) => (a -> f b) -> t a -> f (t b)`

---

`Applicative` and `Traversable` are two interfaces (*typeclasses* in Haskell terms).

- The `Applicative` abstracts over the *effects* we want to perform. In your case it is failure (`Maybe`) but it could also be failure-with-cause (`Either`), input/ouput (`IO`), concurrent input/ouput ([`Concurrently`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/async-2.1.1.1/docs/Control-Concurrent-Async.html#t:Concurrently)) and many others.
- The `Traversable` abstracts over the *type* of container. In your case it is a list (`[]`). But other containers are also `Traversable`: finite containers that have a shape independent of its own values. [Trees](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers-0.5.10.2/docs/Data-Tree.html) and [Maps](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers-0.5.10.2/docs/Data-Map-Strict.html#g:2) are examples. ([Sets](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers-0.5.10.2/docs/Data-Set.html#t:Set) are *not* an example, because their "shape" depends on their values: changing all the elements into the same value will reduce the size of the set.)

`Traversable` is a interface for containers that support "internal iteration". It's basically the `forEach` of other languages. But it also provides you with a result container *of the same shape as the original* which holds the transformed values.

If you don't care for the transformed container, the related [`traverse_`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/Data-Foldable.html#v:traverse_) function discards the result and is only executed for the effects.

The `mapM` function is a synonym for `traverse` that exists for historical reasons.

Answer (score 2):

These are all really good answers. I just want to add to the board that you can find this information much faster with hoogle. If you know what you are looking for good enought that you can produce the type signature for your sought after expression, hoogle will search for it. It is smart enough to understand type variables etc (ie it doesn't matter if you write T and U as you did, or a and b as is common in Haskell).

Taking your example verbatim, `[T] -> (T -> Maybe U) -> Maybe [U]`, you will find among others traverse and mapM, both of which have been mentioned by other peers. Happy hoogling!

Comment: This is good advice, but probably belongs as a comment with a link to [Hoogle](https://www.haskell.org/hoogle/). I personally prefer [Hayoo](http://hayoo.fh-wedel.de) and [Stackage](https://www.stackage.org) which have the same functionality.

Comment: Thanks, this is very useful to know.

Answer (score 1):

While `Data.Traverable.traverse` seems to be the right answer, You may also implement a similar functionality by yourself.

```
isJust :: Maybe a -> Bool
isJust (Just _) = True
isJust _        = False

withList :: (a -> Maybe b) -> [a] -> Maybe [b]
withList f xs | all isJust js = Just (map (\(Just x) -> x) js)
              | otherwise     = Nothing
              where js = map f xs

*Main> withList (\xs -> if all (<10) xs then (Just (sum xs)) else Nothing) [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]] 
Just [6,15,24]
*Main> withList (\xs -> if all (<9) xs then (Just (sum xs)) else Nothing) [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
Nothing
```